# $.ajax trying to get $_GET query variables inside newly loaded ajax page

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

alright i have a div #pagecontainer which loads another php page page_$var.php into it and $var is the page number, i need to get the url query string variables but i cant seem to retrieve them from the newly page.

example: loc=3&option=5

i just cant grab that inside the new page

Comment: `$_GET` is a php predefined constant and it's in the backend. No javascript (jquery) can access it.

Comment: @Zlatev: Unless you output it somewhere javascript can access it.

Answer (score 1):

1) Make sure your page is actually loading - output some static value regardless of the loc and option

2) print out $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] to make sure that your get parameters are getting passed

3) print out a dump of _GET via var_dump($_GET)

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

In the `<head>` of your main page, or anywhere else as long your ajax script is able to get it, add this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $_GET = <?php echo json_encode($_GET) ?>;
</script>
```

You should then be able to use the $_GET variable from Javascript. You can for example test it out in FireBug in FireFox:

```
console.info($_GET);
console.info($_GET['loc']);
console.info($_GET.loc);
```

Remember to sanitize the values before using them for something important...

Comment: On first glance, this looked so wrong I wanted to cry, but you're right. Except, $_GET (the javascript variable) will just be a JSON string, not a JavaScript object. To convert it to a JS object, OP needs to do something like `$_GET = eval('('+'<?php echo json_encode($_GET) ?>'+')');`

Comment: @yc: No, it will be a JS object, or array, or whatever json_encode outputs. Remember that this happens server side. No need for eval or crazy string concatination. It should work right out of the box. Try it out. Works fine here at least :)

Comment: @yc: As you can see on http://codepad.org/vE8VT7E9, you get valid javascript output which will be interpreted fine by the browser :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. **If** `page_1.php?loc=3&option=5` is your query string, then `$_GET['loc']` and `$_GET['option']` are set.

Answer (score 0):

im building it based off of this tutorial
http://tutorialzine.com/2009/09/simple-ajax-website-jquery/

except i have the load_page.php including the page_x.php files
but inside the page_1 file i have it including my connect.php file and then running an sql query "SELECT * FROM pages WHERE Pages.option='mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["option"]);

and i can never get the url query string inside the php file

im loading this as page_1 from the tutorial and am trying to get the GET from the page thats loading this one

here a link 
http://imstillreallybored.com/newstuff/pagetest.php?loc=3&option=5

info loads page_1.php which is where im trying to grab the url query string
im connecting to the database and grabbing information only because im setting the $loc and $option to test numbers until i can get the string

```
<?php
include './connect.php';

$sql = "SELECT
        *                   
        FROM                      
            pages                    
        WHERE                        
            pages.option =".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["option"]);            
        $result = mysql_query($sql);            
        if(!$result)            
        {                
            echo 'The topic could not be displayed, please try again later.';            
            }else{               
                if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)                
                {                    
                    echo 'This doesn&prime;t exist.';               
                }else{                    
                while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))                    
                    {                       
                        if($_GET["loc"]=="3")                       
                    {                        
                    //display content for sports section based on option                         
                    echo $option.'                          
                    <div id="pageContent">                              
                    <div class="clear"></div>                               
                    <h2>'.$row[header].'</h2>                               
                    <p class="meta">                                    
                    <b>Coach(s)</b>:<a href="staff.php">'.$row[coach].'</a>                             
                    </p>                                                                        <div class="post-img">                                      
                    <a href="#"><img src="'.$row[image].'" width="640" height="196" alt="image missing" /></a>                                  
                    </div>                                  
                    <div class="excerpt">                                       
                    <p>'.$row[body].'</p>                                   
                    </div>';                    
                    }                   
                }                
        }            
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: i figured out the problem and got it working i had to change the $.ajax to GET and send different variables which i set on the original page inside 2 hidden fields i then passed the variables in the data to the next page which saved $loc and $option as a GET 
variable and then i used get_file_contents on the php file to load custom ones which connected to my database but since it is grabbing the file and loading it in the other file the GET variables are still there and now it works. its really hard to explain haha

,used var_dump($_GET) alot to check what was in the url query string

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to get url parameters with javascript.

```
<script language="javascript">
function gup( name )
{
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
  var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
  if( results == null )
    return "";
  else
    return results[1];
}
```

From: http://www.netlobo.com/url_query_string_javascript.html